# cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' - maybe not public?

Tags: spring-mvc, jira-rest-api

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rest] in context with path [/PrimeBSOWebService] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 15): Property or field 'partnershipId' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' - maybe not public?] with root cause

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="retrieveFrontEndLoadTableHttpResponse">
    <int:header name="http_statusCode" value="201" overwrite="true" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="retrievePartnershipHttpRequest"
    reply-channel="retrievePartnershipHttpResponse" supported-methods="GET" 
    path="/mutual-fund-product/v1/retrieve/partnerships/{partnership-id}"
    payload-expression="#pathVariables.partnershipId">      
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

```
<int:json-to-object-transformer
    input-channel="retrievePartnershipHttpRequest"
    type="com.cgi.bkifs.rest.prime.contract.partnership.RetrievePartnershipRequest"
    output-channel="retrievePartnershipRequest" object-mapper="customObjectMapper" />

<int:object-to-json-transformer
    input-channel="retrievePartnershipResponse" output-channel="retrievePartnershipHttpResponse"
    object-mapper="customObjectMapperBean" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think it might be because of the different names:
`partnership-id` in the path and `partnershipId` when accessing the path variables